# FacebookMessengerShareButton from react share npm

Tags: reactjs, facebook-messenger, react-share

Cant figure out how to add FacebookMessengerShareButton from react share.
FacebookShareButton works with no issues, but i need Messenger button.
According to docs

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share

- I need to add

> appId (string): Facebook application id

however, i am not sure what id can i put there since page will be shared by other users.

Demo doesnt work as well. This is the error message:

> Sorry, this content isn't available at the moment

Has anyone succeeded in adding facebook messenger share button?
Cheers!

Comment: is FacebookShareButton working properly? I mean, if you have different meta og:image and og:title -s on different routes, is facebook sees them differently?

Comment: FacebookShareButton doesnt need FB user ID. So it works OK.

Comment: I know, but I have issue where facebook cant see og:image and og:title because of client side rendering and I cant find solution, can you give me a snippet or a copy of a code where you declare og tags? thanks

Comment: don think it will help. I just have website page and need to share its url      <FacebookMessengerShareButton title={business.name} appId = "" url={url}><FacebookMessengerIcon size={40} round={true}/></FacebookMessengerShareButton>

Comment: yeah okay I get it. be aware that in the future,  you wont be able to pass different images on facebook using just react, because facebook bots cant see JS.

Comment: it has nothing to do with images. all i need is to be able to share via fb messenger